# How can I solve HTTP 500 error when installing Wordpress in Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I'm getting a HTTP 500 error when installing Wordpress in AWS Elastic Beanstalk using Codepipeline and Github.

I'm using a new downloaded WordPress with some minor changes in the config file, I tested the Beanstalk with a test index.php file and it worked correctly, I get the error when I substitute the files with the Wordpress Files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting my own answer because I couldn't find an answer for my specific problem.

I solved this issue by changing my instance type from t1.micro (free tier) to m2.small, it seems that the Wordpress bundle was too big for the bundle.